# WPF Calendar visible date

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

Quick question: I have a Calendar's SelectedDate property bound to a DateTime value. However, the **calendar displays the "page" with today's date by default**, no matter what is the current SelectedDate value. So when the selected date is, let's say, in 1989, I have to navigate to that year manually to see that the correct date is actually selected. **How do I make it jump to the relevant "page" with the selected date automatically**, whenever the databinding mechanism updates SelectedDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisplayDate

[Calendar.DisplayDate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding to the Calendar.DisplayDate property and hoping to use the SelectedDate, then you'll need to use a OneWay binding.